# espresso - Could not launch intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-espresso

I am trying to test app in android studio with espresso, but without success. I tried for 2 days finding the solution but I still get the exception :

```
    ----- begin exception -----
E/TestRunner: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.example.testoftest/.MainActivity } within 45 seconds. Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time? There could be an animation or something constantly repainting the screen. Or the activity is doing network calls on creation? See the threaddump logs. For your reference the last time the event queue was idle before your activity launch request was 1581611079968 and now the last time the queue went idle was: 1581611079968. If these numbers are the same your activity might be hogging the event queue.
        at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:481)
        at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.launchActivity(ActivityTestRule.java:358)
        at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:529)
        at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2154)
E/TestRunner: ----- end exception -----
```

this is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testoftest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.0.0'
}
```

and this is my androidTest:

```
package com.example.testoftest;


import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;


import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;


public class MainActivityTest {
    //this rule can't start activity and fails
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class); 
    @Test
    public void view_isCorrect() {
        onView(withText("Hello World!")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

I have 8 years old laptop with AMD A6-3400 APU processor may that be a case? Because for example I can't run emulator for android on this CPU.

Comment: Did you try to give any other ``ActivityTestRule`` aka activity to start? Have you ever got any Espresso tests run by this machine?

Comment: No I haven't, unfortunately.